# What is the difference between Clamav and Clamtk?

Tags: clamav

What is the difference between Clamav and Clamtk? I know that both of them are antivirus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ClamAV is the scanner](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) or deamon.

> ClamAV can only detect viruses and move any infected files into a quarantined folder; it cannot remove them from files. ClamAv detects viruses on all platforms, but it is primarily useful for Windows viruses and malware.

[ClamTk is a GUI front-end for ClamAV using gtk2-perl](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

---

It is common practice in Linux to split the frontend/GUI from the actual program so you can use it on a server install.

Answer (score 8):

Clamtk is just a graphical interface to clamav.

```
apt-cache show clamtk
```

(...)

```
Description: graphical front-end for ClamAV
ClamTk is a GUI front-end for ClamAV using perl-Gtk2.
Homepage: http://clamtk.sourceforge.net
```